# What is a good way to brainstorm algorithms on a computer?

Tags: design, algorithms, problem-solving, flowchart

I'm looking for something that allows me to work out an algorithm on a computer similar to how I would do it on a whiteboard. At work, I have a huge whiteboard that I can use for this, but at home, I don't (and can't). This makes it difficult to design algorithms when I'm working on hobby projects. I think better when I use drawings as opposed to text, so pseudocode is no good. I guess what I'm looking for is something like a flowchart program, but that allows a less rigid approach to designing algorithms.

I'd like the program to be cross-platform (Mac, Linux), but I'll be happy even if it just runs on Macs. Free is preferred, but reasonably priced programs are good too. I would prefer programs that people have used and had experiences with, rather than whatever turned up on Google, as I know of some flowchart and mind-mapping software, but haven't really been satisfied with either. I realise that a computer isn't the best platform for doing this kind of stuff, but assume for a moment that it's the only medium I possess.

Comment: Sorry, but this might be off-topic. I don't see how brainstorming algorithms would result in different software than the mind-mapping and note-taking software that's already out there...

Comment: Sorry, I can't possibly see how this is off-topic. It relates _directly_ to programming, is subjective and matches _at least_ criteria 1, 3, 4 and 6 of Jeff's guidelines.

Comment: Then, how is this different from other brainstorming? I fail to see how this question could result in on-topic answers, especially for 1 and 4. Unless this can be clarified, I just see this as "What is a good way to brainstorm on a computer?" with "algorithm" and thus "programming" added as an afterthought; which does add nothing useful to the question that could result in different and more specific answers which are on-topic...

Comment: @Tom: The way you brainstorm other thoughts is fundamentally different from the way you do algorithms. Algorithms have an innate order that makes brainstorming them on a computer much harder (IMHO). The question was asked with the emphasis very much on algorithms. This is NOT a "for programmers" question.

Comment: @TomWij - think about its "topicness" from the other direction:  only someone who codes for a living could answer this question with the level of authority Chinmay is seeking. As such, "for programmer" doesn't seem tacked on to me. "What is good brainstorming software for office workers" will likely yield different results.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: If this is not a question for programmers, then how can it be on-topic?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi, @JimLeonardo: Algorithms are a part of Discrete Algorithmic Mathematics and are not only used is Computer Science, mathematicians also form algorithms (http://io9.com/5443389/mathematicians-create-algorithm-so-complex-no-computer-can-use-ityet) and they aren't programmers at all. There is no way in which your topic can result in on-topic answers different than would be given on a Mathematics forum or from more general mind-mapping/note-taking software...

Comment: See it from another way: An answer as stupid as "Take a drawing tablet and Photoshop and draw out the algorithm on your screen" is a valid answer to your question, while there will never be an answer specific to algorithms. A better way would be to ask if someone had experience with brainstorming algorithms on the computer, as that would result in unique on-topic answers...

Comment: WWF is an exception to this as it's a new Foundation from Microsoft, and then still it is more focused on developing algorithms than brainstorming them...

Comment: I don't believe it - we've got topic police on the programmers site?  Clearly the OP uses this in context of programming.  This is not SO - I think you are over doing it a bit with the "off topic" nonsense.  If you don;t want to read about it, click on another question.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to brainstorm some design stuff that takes more complexity than Notepad can cope with, I usually just use a pencil/pen and paper.

Comment: And in what way does this answer the question?

Comment: I expected a pencil and paper answer, which is why I said "I realise that a computer isn't the best platform for doing this kind of stuff, but assume for a moment that it's the only medium I possess." I don't want to do it on paper, because you either spend too much effort erasing useless bits or waste a whole lot of paper, neither of which I'm too fond of doing.

Comment: I bet if you write small and turn off your computer, the paper use in design will be a net gain for the planet's ecosystem. You could also try using the brain before writing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sketch tool called **[Pencil Project](http://www.evolus.vn/pencil/)** that I saw by this days. 
This is a open source project that runs at FireFox or stand-alone, but no Mac version yet.

**[Here](http://alternativeto.net/software/pencil-project/)** you can get other alternatives too. (provide by AlternativeTo service)

Maybe you find one that fits with your need.

Anyway, I prefer whiteboard to do this.

Comment: Glad to see there's finally a standalone version. How new is that? (Also, who does all their prototyping in Firefox? ...)

Comment: I don´t know too. :) Standalone version is provided by XULRunner, not a real standalone. I tried and got some bugs, but the project is cool.

Answer (score -1):

[Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) allows you to brainstorm and develop algorithms in a flowchart way.

[image: WWF Chart]
<sub>(source: [windowsworkflowfoundation.eu](http://www.windowsworkflowfoundation.eu/images/Sequential.jpg))</sub>

Comment: From the description on the linked page, it seems to be pretty .NET centric -- ties with Visual Studio etc.

Comment: This should only be used for the purpose of brainstorming and testing, when it's fine you could copy the right algorithm into your own language... Having Visual Studio indeed is a down-side for some.

Comment: flowcharts are the last thing i would use for brainstorming

Answer (score -1):

[Livescribe](http://www.livescribe.com/en-us/) might be a solution for you, aside from picking up a Bamboo or Intuous.  Even though it is pen and paper, it can create PDFs of your writings/diagrams on the computer.